# Android Key Store - Name of Organizational Unit

Tags: android, google-play-services, keystore, android-keystore

I have developed a nice Android application with PhoneGap build.

But now I am unable to upload it to google playstore for signing issue.

After playing with Google, I got a way to sign it using **keystore** tool.

Everything is fine.

But it is asking for ***Name of Organizational Unit***.

Now what is it? Where can I find it? What's it's necessity?

I am unable to proceed without it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is the name of the department of your company in which you work, if you work at one. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html) for example.

I usually put IT in that field.

Comment: Yes I got it. I thought it was any unit **eg: UPM, FGD etc** . Thanks.

Comment: I builded an app without filling it, should I fill it and re-build it? or it will work without it too?

Answer (score 1):

**Name of Organizational Unit** refer to *your company department*.

If you are working in IT Software department, then just fill in **IT Software** in this field.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you meant to say the `keytool` tool not the `keystore` tool, as I'm not aware of a `keystore` tool :)

I just leave most fields blank if I can. You can do this by using the `dname` argument to `keytool`. For example:

`keytool -genkeypair -alias foo -keyalg RSA -keystore mystore.p12 -dname CN=JoeBloggs`

This will set the CN ("first and last name") to JoeBloggs, but leave all the other fields (including organizational unit) blank. You can see the result using a command such as: `keytool -list -keystore mystore.p12 -v`